# My application for Android doesn't work on my Samsung Galaxy Gio

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe6

I have a problem regarding an Android app that I am writing using Embarcadero Delphi XE6. Because it's my first app on a mobile phone, I wanted to do something basic, to get the hang of it: a button and a label. When I tap the button, the label prints the famous message **Hello World!**

I followed every piece of the tutorials about how to link my phone, a [Samsung Galaxy Gio (S5660)](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_gio_s5660-3741.php), with Android 2.3.6 installed. Everything works perfectly, until I actually get to run the small app.

At first, I get the message **Application does not support this device** Digging further, I read on a page from Delphi's assistance files, that a workaround for this is to uncheck a checkbox in the *Deployment* page. I did that and the message disappeared. But the app simply crashed, So, this workaround isn't good.

Where am I mistaking? What haven't I done for this little app to work on my phone? I installed every available SDK from API version 9 and above so I don't think that the SDK is the problem.

Help! :)

LE: The AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.embarcadero.Project1"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="Project1" 
        android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="Project1"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="Project1" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />
    </application>
</manifest>   
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

The code that is written in the unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnPushMe: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure btnPushMeClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.btnPushMeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Label1.Text:='Hello World!';
end;

end.
```

Comment: you have to post some code,or your logcat for us to help you

Comment: also, post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Done. I added both the code and the .xml

Comment: funny that 2 das ago i also made my first mobile app, also has the same phone and also the same eror ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your device is simply not supported (like Delphi states), check the [manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development).

Your device (Samsung GT-S5660) has a ARMv6 CPU and DelphiXE6 needs at least ARMv7 **with** NEON support and a GPU.

**Update:**

A more extended device compatibility list can be found [here](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) (Thanks @Remy Lebeau)

Comment: Just FYI, the manual lists only a fraction of available devices, devices that Embarcadero itself has tested. There are many more devices tested by users listed on the [Delphi Wikia](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) site.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It seems to me that I missed that part.